# Program crashed in the last step in test Tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0

Tags: tensorflow, testing

When using Tensorflow 2.0.0 and split dataset into train-set and test-set. The training and testing code is as following:

```
for epoch in range(params.num_epochs):
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dist_dataset):
        DO TRAINING HERE....
    if epoch % params.num_epoch_record == 0:
        for step, (x_test, y_test) in enumerate(test_dist_dataset):
            DO TESTing HERE....
        checkpoint.step.assign_add(1)
        save_path = manager.save()
        logger.info("Saved checkpoint {}".format(save_path))
```

However, when after the last test data in `enumerate(test_dist_dataset)` the program will crash and shows up:

```
F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_2d_gpu.h:964] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel( SwapDimension1And2InTensor3UsingTiles<T, kNumThreads, kTileSize, kTileSize, conjugate>, total_tiles_count, kNumThreads, 0, d.stream(), input, input_dims, output) status: Internal: invalid configuration argument
```

So, how it occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: What is your input? What model are you training?

Comment: I use mirroredstrategy to train my model, and the input and model is set by myself

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem is related to the batch size. I am using nvidia docker 19.12 and data generator. The code works well with one gpu and the problem happened only with mirroredstrategy in the model.predict.

When the total number of data can not be divided by the batch_size perfectly, the error happens. For example, you have 5 data and batch_size is 2. The 3rd batch will have only one data and brings a problem.

The solution is either throw away the last data, or in my case, add some dummy data to fill up the last batch.